# React router not redirecting to root path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React App and want to load diff routes for loggedin user and logged out user.

```
class App extends React.Component{
   // usual react constructor ond state and required methods
   PreAuthRender = () => {
    return(
      <>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <LoginScreen onLoginSuccess={this.onLoginSuccess} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/signup" >
          <SignupScreen onSignupSucess={this.onSignupSucess}/>
        </Route>        
        
      </>
    )
  }

  PostAuthRender = () => {
    return(
      <>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <LandingPage />
        </Route>
        {
          routes.map((route, index) => (
            <RouteRenderer {...route} key={index}/>
          ))
        }
        
      </>
    )
  }
  
 render(
     return(
       <React.Fragment> 
      {this.renderAppHeader()}
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>                     
            {
              (api_key_status == "missing" || api_key_status == "failed") ? this.PreAuthRender() : this.PostAuthRender()
            }
                        
            <Redirect to="/" />
            
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
     )
   )

}
```

wherein in PostAuthRender, routes is an array of routes

```
routes = [
  {
    path: '/profile',
    component: ComponentToRenderOnMatch,
    exact: true/false
  },...
]
```

And The route Renderer Component

```
const RouteRenderer = (route) => {
  return(
    <Route
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact}
      render={(props) => (
        <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

Every thing routes perfectly as per the need.

**The only problem** is that if route does not matches any of the routes then it should execute the `<Redirect to="/" />` and redirect me to either the login screen if the user is not authenticated or if loggged in then to the feed page. But that does not happen.

Instead, the url stays the same and nothing is diplayed on the browser.

What am I missing, is this not the correct way of conditionally routing your app?

Comment: Did you find any error messages in the console? What version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: @SaianshSingh No. No error messages on the console and the header part renders but nothing else. Its just header(which is outside the browserrouter) and below that is blank. I am using 5.2.0 version of react-router